# Actionscript hitTest drawing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I've gotten actions on a frame, what I'm trying to do is have a `hitTest` that triggers `gotoAndStop(<lose frame>)` when the shape I am drawing collides with the `touchTest`. The only issue I'm having is I cannot get the `hitTest` to register directly when the line hits it, it only registers after the next click event. The other issue I'm encountering is a hit box on the `touchTest` is many times larger than the actual image of the symbol.

```
var myshape:Shape;
myshape = new Shape();
myshape.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xC807DE);
var alreadyDrawn:Shape;
alreadyDrawn = new Shape();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, activateDraw);
function activateDraw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myshape.graphics.moveTo(mouseX,mouseY);
    addChild(myshape);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);
}

function lineDraw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myshape.graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
    checkIt();
}
function stopDraw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    alreadyDrawn.graphics.copyFrom(myshape.graphics);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);
}

function checkIt()
{
    if (alreadyDrawn.hitTestObject(touchTest) == true)
    {
        trace("wall");
        myshape.graphics.clear();
        myshape.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xC807DE);
        alreadyDrawn.graphics.clear(); // clear this too
        stopDraw(null); // stop active draw, if any
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it only registers after the next click event

This is because the object you are testing the collision against `alreadyDrawn` doesn't have a collision area yet. You create the new shape, add your listeners, and test your collision in your `lineDraw()` using the method `checkIt()`, but the shape doesn't have a collision area until your mouse up function `stopDraw()` where it does `alreadyDrawn.graphics.copyFrom(myshape.graphics);`

So to fix this you would have to create the graphics object earlier. The change could look something like this (at the top):

```
var alreadyDrawn:Shape = new Shape();
alreadyDrawn.graphics.copyFrom(myshape.graphics);
```

That would give a collision area to test against in `checkIt()`

---

> The other issue I'm encountering is a hit box on the touchTest is many
>   times larger than the actual image of the symbol.

For this issue, you can access the clip or a symbol inside it and grab its bounds relative to the parent of the `alreadyDrawn` shape. Then you can use the bounds of both shapes to test for a collision. This will give you a more accurate collision area for testing:

```
function checkIt()
{
    var alreadyDrawnBounds:Rectangle = alreadyDrawn.getBounds( alreadyDrawn.parent );
    var testBounds:Rectangle = touchTest.someSymbolName.getBounds( alreadyDrawn.parent );
    //could also try this instead:
    //var alreadyDrawnBounds:Rectangle = alreadyDrawn.getBounds( touchTest.parent );
    //var testBounds:Rectangle = touchTest.getBounds( touchTest );      

    if ( alreadyDrawnBounds.intersects( testBounds ) ) {
        trace("wall");
        myshape.graphics.clear();
        myshape.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xC807DE);
        alreadyDrawn.graphics.clear(); // clear this too
        stopDraw(null); // stop active draw, if any
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you typed this in verbatim? The line `touchTest.someSymbolName`, "someSymbolName" will need to be a named child of your touchTest asset if it's a movieClip. Otherwise, use the commented out part underneath it. Or if the touchTest asset was generated dynamically or you don't have a symbol name you can always use `getChildAt( value )`

Comment: I made a slight change to the answer in the second half commented code. Getting the bounds of the display object, and using the display object as the parameter provides an accurate collision area.

Comment: I'm honestly just the worst, I am new to actionscript so I created the touchTest in cs6 using the tool and converted it to a symbol so can I assume it's not dynamic?  The name of this symbol is someSymbolName variable? I'm probably in over my head here, I'm going to go back and relearn as3 after I fix this error.

Comment: Try using the code I have commented out, that might help your giant collision area issue. As far as what is happening "someSymbolName" would be a symbol inside your `touchTest` asset. You would have to select it, and give it a name like "someSymbolName", then you could access it with `touchTest.someSymbolName`. But for now, try the code that is commented out instead, and see if that works.

Comment: I tried the commented code with no luck, it doesn't spew errors there is just no reaction(trace is not executed) I'll try to figure out how to change the name of the instance of which touchTest is an object of? Screen shot, I assume you're refering to the intance of: http://prntscr.com/50f16y

Comment: Hmm, is touchTest a child of another movie clip? Or is it just on the stage?

Comment: It's just on the stage, sorry that I might have been confusing you :L

Comment: Ok then you are definitely accessing it correctly. I would try to perhaps make a symbol (movieclip) inside your touchTest asset. Then give it an instance name, and access it with touchTest.someSymbolName.

Comment: Ok I made a symbol in my touchTest symbol and inserted it into the first line of code and tested, no errors but the collisions happened seemingly randomly, not when the line was touching the touchTest symbol or the new symbol.

Comment: Hmm I'm sure there are some other factors coming into play. I wouldn't know without looking at it, but my suggestion is to keep playing around with it. Using `getBounds` is definitely going to be the simplest and most accurate way to detect the collision of two objects, and using `getBounds` and passing the same display object is going to give you the most accurate visible area (ie- `touchTest.getBounds( touchTest )`).

Comment: One sec I'll send you some screen shots to maybe get a better picture of what's going on. http://prntscr.com/510w0x frame nothing selected. http://prntscr.com/510w95 touchtest selected(blue box). InBox what I named the movieclip inside the touchtest asset(also blue box) http://prntscr.com/510wkq